# reload interface while keeping data?

Tags: interface

I'm still learning the new 2.8 layout. I screwed up my interface somehow and I can't scroll in / out.

I try doing load startup file, but it resets me back to the default cube.

How can I reset the interface while keeping the model I've been working on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your project file and then (re-)open it without loading the stored UI. This can be accomplished through *File > Open* with the *Load UI* option unchecked.

[image: File browser]