# Edit Mode - XRay Clutter - Edges/Faces/Verts

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, visibility, orthographic

The picture on the left is a subdivided Cube in a fresh new project in edit mode.
The picture on the right is that same cube in edit mode but in my current project.
As you can see: obscured edges are partially visible, without me toggling Z.
There are slightly less edges visible in perspective view (as opposed to orthographic) but it is still significant enough to cause clutter.

I've tried porting the project from 2.8 to 2.81 but it seems to be project specific.

How do i get get rid of this pseudo x-Ray effect and display only the edges/faces/verts that are not obscured?
Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: Can you try to [load the project without it's UI settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160129/reload-interface-while-keeping-data)? Judging by the UI layout it seems you've ported the project from 2.79 to 2.8x and maybe something went wrong there.

Comment: You're a hero. That actually solved it. even though i did create it in 2.8 I just adjusted the UI to look like 2.79 since I'm used to that layout.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you just toggled the actual X-Ray mode

[image]

and changed its alpha value.

[image]

Comment: I assumed that wouldn't be the case because they wrote "without me toggling Z".

Comment: Ye that's correct. I did not Toggle X Ray or the Z. Also normal X ray modedarkens the faces as you see.

Comment: @RobertGützkow X-Ray is not the Z. His view looks exactly the same as X-Ray mode with alpha set to 1.

Comment: @checkerbox Can you provide the blend file?

Comment: @unwave X-Ray is ALT + Z, so it was close enough to the actual shortcut that I assumed that this is what was meant. Perhaps I made too many assumptions though.