# Navigation gizmo missing after loading a file

Tags: navigation, gizmo

I am using Blender 2.82a on Mac, and it seems every time I open this particular file, my navigation gizmo (viewport top right) along with the zoom, pan, and camera buttons that are usually below it are missing!

I have tried to Load Factory Settings, and they reappear in the new and empty file. But whenever I return to my Blender file they remain missing!

Not sure if it's a stupid question, and in reality it's just a hot-key that I may have accidentally pressed, but I am new to Blender and would really love the help with this!

Please and thank you!

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Maybe the issue is that when you open the file you are loading the interface associated with the file. You can open blender, then go to file open, but before you press enter, press n to enable the options for loading. Deselect loadUI. But know also that the Guizmo can be enabled or disabled in the 3d vieport  or using Ctrl `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport nagivation gizmo can be activated in the *Viewport Gizmos* options by ticking the checkbox with the *Navigate* label.

[image: Navigate Gizmo]

If you don't want to load the UI layout and settings from an existing project, disable *Load UI* in the file browser as shown in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160132/74827).

Comment: Ah, amazing - nice and easy. Sorry, I knew it would be a simple answer but couldn't figure it out.  Disabling LoadUI  makes it much easier when I am playing with multiple files which have passed through multiple hands! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user98559 No problem, that's what this Q&A website is for.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure Gizmos are enabled by clicking on the gizmo button(1) then click on the arrow next to it (2) after that enable navigate(3)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers go to Edit - Preferences - Interface and in the Editors section ensure that the Navigation Controls Box is ticked (to view the zoom, move, camera and grid buttons).

[image: Image of Blender 2.92 UI]